# Laravel 8 passport Auth::login access token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

Laravel version: 8

Passport verion: 10

I have an existing laravel system that works perfectly as it is.
Now I am extending functionality so that users can login using another external site as well. Much like social logins.
I made the middleware so that the user gets created in our laravel users table - this works fine.
Once the user is created and I run:

```
\Auth::login($user);
```

This seems to do what it's suppose to, but my question is, is there a way to return the oauth access token for the frontend to consume?

Any help or point in direction is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I overlooked the createToken function - this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can associate the OAuth token with a user session (keep it in a database together) so that you don't have to pass the token to your frontend. The frontend just uses user session, and the backend knows which OAuth token to use with which user session.

Comment: Do you have some more information about this? Right now the frontend for the existing users works by passing the access token to the laravel API endpoints. Since the external users doesn't have an access token but is only created in the user table - Is there an Auth function that creates or associates a token for a user? or how can I create one and return to the client?